# What happens if i open a file that is already open in C++

Tags: c++, file, fstream

Imagine I have an output file declared.

What would happen if I open it twice with this code? Would it still work?

```
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("record.txt", std::ofstream::app);
outfile.open("record.txt", std::ofstream::app);
```

Comment: What happens when you try it, does it still work?

Comment: i am debugging other errors, writing a big program currently.

Comment: @muhammadmuzaib: Does your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) not allow you to store more than one project on your hard drive? Can't you write a small test program?

Comment: I compiled the program and it ran without errors.  And for my project, I found a way that I wouldn't have to open the file twice.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation on `std::ofstream::open`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open), it behaves the same way as `std::basic_filebuf::open`. According to [the documentation on that function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open), the operation will fail if the file is already open.

This means that the second call to `std::ofstream::open` will put the stream in a state in which the [`failbit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) is set. As a consequence, most subsequent operations on the stream will fail, until that bit is cleared. In order to clear the bit, you will have to call [`std::ofstream::clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear). After that, the stream will behave normally again.

The answer above applies to attempting to open two files using the same `std::ofstream` object, irrespective of whether it is the same file or not.

Attempting to open the same file using two different `std::ofstream` objects (which you are not doing in your question) is a completely different issue. That is not recommended, because, even if the operating system allows a file to be opened multiple times, this will probably give each stream object its own buffer, which are not synchronized with the buffers of the other streams. This could cause the file to become corrupt. However, if both streams access completely different parts of the file that are far apart, it will probably work (but I still don't recommend taking the risk).

Comment: so if the operation fails, we can still write to the file tho right? or would the program not compile?

Comment: @muhammadmuzaib *"would the program not compile?"* -- a runtime operation never causes compilation to fail.